# CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/e/c/RxSwift/3.0.0-rc.1/RxSwift.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am getting this error while trying to make a pod install

CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/e/c/RxSwift/3.0.0-rc.1/RxSwift.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/e/c/RxSwift/3.0.1/RxSwift.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/e/c/RxSwift/3.1.0/RxSwift.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/2/e/c/RxSwift/3.2.0/RxSwift.podspec.json Response: SSL connect error

I tried to do `pod repo remove trunk` but still didn't work. Any clue what I could be missing?